# How do I get environment variables of an EKS pod from the frontend?

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

Essentially I have a set of 6 pods running on an EKS cluster all running the same frontend React app and I'm trying to simply display the `HOSTNAME` of a pod in a `<p>` tag to test which pod my Load Balancer is hitting.

Is there a way to fetch this environment variable from the application level without setting up a backend?

Answer (score 0):

No, your backend react pod will have send the pod IP as the K8s LB is abstracting it with a service IP.

For example:
https://github.com/paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes/blob/main/src/app/server.js